# Visual Studio and Swagger/Swashbuckle - Deploy WebAPI that has DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I deploy my WebAPI that has `DateTimeOffset` as a parameter it just treats it like DateTime type when I use Add `REST API client...` in Visual Studio project.

```
** WebAPI:

public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(DateTimeOffset myDate) { ... }

** Swagger: 
SwaggerUI show type as a datetime..


** Client Project:
Add REST API Client...
```

> Comes down as a DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to get the datetimeoffset to work when importing the swagger xml into visual studio? Thanks Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet of what works for me

Web:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateFollowUp(string uniqueid, DateTimeOffset? workStart, ....){....}
```

Mobile:

```
  public async Task CreateFollowUP(string uniqueid, DateTimeOffset? workStart, ...)
    {
        try
        {
            await RetryPolicy().ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                using (client)
                {
                    var fullurl = RestUrl + $"followups/CreateFollowUp?uniqueid={uniqueid}&workStart={workStart.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")}...";
```